# jruby makes rescue Exception nil with rescue Java::System.out

Tags: jruby, jrubyonrails

The error.class output changes on `the 2nd execution` of this code in Jruby script/console.

```
begin
 raise "something went wrong"
rescue Java::System.out => java_error
  puts java_error.inspect
rescue Exception => error
  puts "error class: #{error.inspect}"
  puts "Why is the error class nilClass?. It should have been RuntimeError"
end
```

The first time, the output is

```
error class: nil
Why is the error class nilClass?. It should have been RuntimeError
=> nil
```

The second time, the output is

```
error class: #<RuntimeError: something went wrong>
Why is the error class nilClass?. It should have been RuntimeError
=> nil
```

It appears the usage of Java:: in the first rescue block is making the error nil somehow, the first time it is encountered. I used Java::System.out for this example but it happens with any java class.

environment

```
jruby 1.6.5 (ruby-1.8.7-p330) (2011-10-25 9dcd388) 
(Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_26) [linux-amd64-java]
```

Any idea?, @Nick?